# how can I check database connection to mysql in django

Tags: python, django, django-settings

how can I do it?

I thought, I can read something from database, but it looks too much, is there something like?:

```
settings.DATABASES['default'].check_connection()
```

Comment: Your project wouldn't start if something is wrong with your database connection. Or even `python manage.py shell` will return error.

Comment: @anupsabraham my connection was not working but shell worked

Answer (score 52, accepted):

All you need to do is start a application and if its not connected it will fail. Other way you can try is on shell try following -

```
from django.db import connections
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
db_conn = connections['default']
try:
    c = db_conn.cursor()
except OperationalError:
    connected = False
else:
    connected = True
```

Comment: my connection was not working but my application did run

Comment: @KevinZhao so whats an issue?

Comment: my issue was that I used the wrong database name/user/password in the `settings.py` file, changed that and everything worked

Comment: Even if dbname or username/password is set wrong, running shell will throw errors. Which version of django are you using?
`(1049, "Unknown database 'dbname’”)` / `(1045, "Access denied for user 'user'@'host' (using password: YES)”)` These are the errors you'll get while trying to run `python manage.py shell` with wrong db settings.

Comment: Now it is ok to just use `django.db.connection.ensure_connection()`

Comment: This will not actually work until you execute something on the cursor

Comment: Yeah this is hairy, especially if this is needed in a health check. Django caches connections, so even if you do work on the cursor, you can't be certain the DB server actually accepts new connections. Also to those who writes that it isn't needed as Django won't start without the db: the big use case is regular health checks, and the DB can go down later in the cycle.

Comment: Neither this nor `ensure_connection` works if the app loses the DB connection while the app is running - as BjornW said, this is essential for health checks. You'll want to execute an actual query - `SELECT 1` is sufficient for this.

Comment: you may want to see `check_database_connected()`
here
https://github.com/mozilla-services/python-dockerflow/blob/master/src/dockerflow/django/checks.py

Comment: The else block will be very helpful especially if you are checking it in a while loop. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 48):

Run the shell

```
python manage.py shell
```

Execute this script

```py
import django
print(django.db.connection.ensure_connection())
```

If it print `None` means everything is okay, otherwise it will throw an error if something wrong happens on your db connection

Answer (score 36):

It's an old question but it needs an updated answer

```sh
python manage.py check --database default
```

If you're not using default or if you want to test other databases listed in your settings just name it.

It is available since version 3.1 +

Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#available-commands)

Comment: ```usage: manage.py check [-h] [--tag TAGS] [--list-tags] [--deploy] [--fail-level {CRITICAL,ERROR,WARNING,INFO,DEBUG}] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}] [--settings SETTINGS]
                       [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback] [--no-color] [--force-color]
                       [app_label [app_label ...]]
manage.py check: error: unrecognized arguments: --database```

Comment: It is available in version 3.1 +

Comment: I will update the comment thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 14):

I use the following Django management command called `wait_for_db`:

```
import time

from django.db import connection
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    """Django command that waits for database to be available"""

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        """Handle the command"""
        self.stdout.write('Waiting for database...')
        db_conn = None
        while not db_conn:
            try:
                connection.ensure_connection()
                db_conn = True
            except OperationalError:
                self.stdout.write('Database unavailable, waiting 1 second...')
                time.sleep(1)

        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Database available!'))
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: I'd add a limit to those attempts and sleeps, to avoid an infinite loop. something like `for _ in range(10)` instead of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 5):

*Assuming you needed this because of docker, BUT is not limitted to docker, remember this is at the end of the day Bash, and thus works everywhere *NIX.*

You will first need to be using `django-environ`, since it will make this a whole lot easier.

The `DATABASE_URL` environment variable will be used inside your Django app, and here. Your settings would look like this:

```
import environ

env = environ.Env()

...

DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db('DATABASE_URL'),
    'other': env.db('DATABASE_OTHER_URL')  # for illustration purposes
}

...
```

Your environment variables should look something like this: (more info [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/))

```
# This works with ALL the databases django supports ie (mysql/mssql/sqlite/...)
DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:pass@name_of_box:5432/database_name
DATABASE_OTHER_URL=oracle://user:pass@/(description=(address=(host=name_of_box)(protocol=tcp)(port=1521))(connect_data=(SERVICE_NAME=EX)))
```

Inside your `entrypoint.sh` do something like this:

```
function database_ready() {
  # You need to pass a single argument called "evironment_dsn"
  python << EOF
import sys
import environ
from django.db.utils import ConnectionHandler, OperationalError

env = environ.Env()
try:
   ConnectionHandler(databases={'default': env.db('$1')})['default'].ensure_connection()
except (OperationalError, DatabaseError):
   sys.exit(-1)
sys.exit(0)
EOF
}
```

Then, lets say you want to wait for your main db [the postgres in this case], you add this inside the same `entrypoint.sh`, under the `database_ready` function.

```
until database_ready DATABASE_URL; do
  >&2 echo "Main DB is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done
```

This will only continue, IF postgres is up and running. What about oracle? Same thing, under the code above, we add:

```
until database_ready DATABASE_OTHER_URL; do
  >&2 echo "Secondary DB is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done
```

Doing it this way will give you a couple of advantages:

1. you don't need to worry about other dependencies such as binaries and the likes.
2. you can switch databases and not have to worry about this breaking. (code is 100% database agnostic)

Answer (score 3):

Create a file **your_app_name/management/commands/waitdb.py** and paste the bellow.

```py
import time
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.db import connection
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
from django.utils.translation import ngettext


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Checks database connection'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            '--seconds',
            nargs='?',
            type=int,
            help='Number of seconds to wait before retrying',
            default=1,
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            '--retries',
            nargs='?',
            type=int,
            help='Number of retries before exiting',
            default=3,
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        wait, retries = options['seconds'], options['retries']
        current_retries = 0
        while current_retries < retries:
            current_retries += 1
            try:
                connection.ensure_connection()
                break
            except OperationalError:
                plural_time = ngettext('second', 'seconds', wait)
                self.stdout.write(
                    self.style.WARNING(
                        f'Database unavailable, retrying after {wait} {plural_time}!'
                    )
                )
                time.sleep(wait)
```

```sh
python manage.py waitdb --seconds 5 --retries 2
python manage.py waitdb # defaults to 1 seconds & 3 retries
```

Comment: For some reason. it did not help in my case. This code runs OK, no exception, and after that I still get OperationalError SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly. Django 4.2.5

Answer (score 2):

I had a more complicated case where I am using mongodb behind djongo module, and RDS mysql. So not only is it multiple databases, but djongo throws an SQLDecode error instead. I also had to execute and fetch to get this working:

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    # Quick database check here
    from django.db import connections
    from django.db.utils import OperationalError
    dbs = settings.DATABASES.keys()
    for db in dbs:
        db_conn = connections[db]  # i.e. default
        try:
            c = db_conn.cursor()
            c.execute("""SELECT "non_existent_table"."id" FROM "non_existent_table" LIMIT 1""")
            c.fetchone()
            print("Database '{}' connection ok.".format(db))  # This case is for djongo decoding sql ok
        except OperationalError as e:
            if 'no such table' in str(e):
                print("Database '{}' connection ok.".format(db))  # This is ok, db is present
            else:
                raise  # Another type of op error
        except Exception:  # djongo sql decode error
            print("ERROR: Database {} looks to be down.".format(db))
            raise
```

I load this in my app `__init__.py`, as I want it to run on startup only once and only if DEBUG is enabled. Hope it helps!

Comment: The approach is looking good. Instead of querying for a non-existent user table, I'm doing a `select Db from mysql.db LIMIT 1` as the query. It has a high expectancy of success.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Javier's answer is no longer working. He's one I put together to perform the task of checking database availability in a Docker entrypoint, assuming you have the `psycopg2` library available (you're running a Django application, for instance):

````
function database_ready() {
    python << EOF
import psycopg2
try:
    db = psycopg2.connect(host="$1", port="$2", dbname="$3", user="$4", password="$5")
except:
    exit(1)

exit(0)
EOF
}

until database_ready $DATABASE_HOST $DATABASE_PORT $DATABASE_NAME $DATABASE_USER $DATABASE_PASSWORD; do
  >&2 echo "Database is unavailable at $DATABASE_HOST:$DATABASE_PORT/$DATABASE_NAME - sleeping..."
  sleep 1
done
echo "Database is ready - $DATABASE_HOST:$DATABASE_PORT/$DATABASE_NAME"```
````