# Django: Connection refused after switching to MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, django-celery

I'm working on my first Django project and I kept hitting the limits of sqlite. So I decided to switch to MySQL before adding lots of additional test data. Ever since no page in my Django app loads anymore (neither the admin nor the project pages). I get no error message until Chrome eventually displays "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

I added the following to my settings:

```
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'db_name',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'OPTIONS': {
       'read_default_file': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my.cnf'),
    },
```

The my.cnf file referenced above looks like this:

```
[client]
database = dbname
user = username
password = password
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 512M

wait_timeout = 604800
interactive_timeout = 28800
```

It's definetely being used, as changing the database name in the file causes Django to connect to a different db.

The project uses Celery, so I also modified the Celery result backend:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+mysql://user:password@localhost:3306/dbname'
```

Django can connect to the database (see tests like this one: [how can I check database connection to mysql in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098797/how-can-i-check-database-connection-to-mysql-in-django)). I migrated my content according the second answer to this question: [What's the best way to migrate a Django DB from SQLite to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034910/whats-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-django-db-from-sqlite-to-mysql) without any errors. All data are present in phpMyAdmin. There's nothing in the MySQL error log. Neither Django nor Celery outputs any error in the debug console/command line. I installed mysqlclient and (for Celery) SQLAlchemy.

Switching back the the original sqlite configuration remedies the problem, so it's definitely linked to the MySQL db. What am I overlooking? Have I missed some vital configuration step? Is there a way to get more error messages? Especially the complete lack of the latter really has me flummoxed.

Trying to get objescts from the database bia the Python console results in `´mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')`, which once more points to a MySQL issue. Closing old connections fixed this error, which did not reappear so far, but the page still doesn't load.

Comment: What's the error stack trace; please include that in your question

Comment: @rtindru There is no error. That's my biggest problem, as I don't know what to test or change.

Comment: `python manage.py runserver` executes without issue?

Comment: @rtindru Yes. "System check identified no issues (0 silenced).", et cetera

Comment: Can you run `python manage.py check` once?
Are you sure you're hitting the right endpoint in chrome?

Comment: @rtindru Check identifies no issues. And I'm sure, renaming the old sqlite configuration to "default" and reloading the same URL works.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the local mysql instance using `mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: @rtindru Yes, I am. Testing the connection via PyCharm also works, as does connecting to the db via the python console. But trying to get objects from the database results in `mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')`, so that's progress.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? There are a number of reasons for this issue: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html
Can you check if the user `user` in your case has permissions for the databases you need? You can do a `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'localhost'`. Also that the databases indeed exist?

Comment: Also can you confirm that your MySQL server is running on the TCP port and not on a socket? Do a `ps aux | grep mysql` and share the dump here, also do a `cat my.cnf` and share the same here.

Comment: @rtindru Closing old conenctions fixed this issue. It was likely conencted to Celery, as I found several reports of long Celery tasks leading to this error. So I'm back to my starting point - I can execute runserver, I can query the db via the Django console and get the expected results, but no page loads, the PyCharm Debugger won't load any variables and no error message shows anywhere.